# Performance difference between Map.has vs Map.get

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6

Is there any advantage to use `Map.has()` for checking if key exists in `Map` instead of using `Map.get()`? *(Other than code readability reasons)*

I checked ES2015 language specifications and both methods seems the same except the return value so I believe the performance is the same but maybe there are some other aspects I don't know of that could affect performance here.

**Map.prototype.has ( key )**

> The following steps are taken:
>
> Let M be the this value. If Type(M) is not Object, throw a TypeError
>   exception. If M does not have a [[MapData]] internal slot, throw a
>   TypeError exception. Let entries be the List that is the value of M’s
>   [[MapData]] internal slot. Repeat for each Record {[[key]], [[value]]}
>   p that is an element of entries, If p.[[key]] is not empty and
>   SameValueZero(p.[[key]], key) is true, return true. Return false.

[Map.prototype.has method specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map.prototype.has)

**Map.prototype.get ( key )**

> The following steps are taken:
>
> Let M be the this value. If Type(M) is not Object, throw a TypeError
>   exception. If M does not have a [[MapData]] internal slot, throw a
>   TypeError exception. Let entries be the List that is the value of M’s
>   [[MapData]] internal slot. Repeat for each Record {[[key]], [[value]]}
>   p that is an element of entries, If p.[[key]] is not empty and
>   SameValueZero(p.[[key]], key) is true, return p.[[value]]. Return
>   undefined.

[Map.prototype.get method specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map.prototype.get)

Comment: It would depend, does your code require there to be a difference between the value being missing, and the value being `undefined`?

Comment: Yes, performance is the same (but I cannot think performance will matter at all). `has` is also clearer if that is what you need (you don't need to think about a value being present, but being "falsey").

Comment: ...is this really something you need optimisation with? Is this *really* a bottleneck in your application?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One reason why `Map.has` could be preferable would be if the key happens to exist, but the value is falsey. If you use `Map.get`, you'll also have to check whether the value `=== undefined` (and even that does not guarantee that the key does not exist - the key may exist, but have a value of `undefined`):

```js
// Not good enough:
const map = new Map();
map.set('foo', 0);
if (map.get('foo')) {
  console.log('Map has "foo" key');
}
```

```js
// Better, but not foolproof:
const map = new Map();

map.set('foo', 0);
map.set('bar', undefined);

const valAtFoo = map.get('foo');
if (valAtFoo !== undefined) {
  console.log('Map has "foo" key');
}

// Incorrect:
const valAtBar = map.get('bar');
if (valAtBar !== undefined) {
  console.log('Map has "bar" key');
}
```

```js
// Solution: use map.has instead of map.get
const map = new Map();
map.set('foo', 0);
map.set('bar', undefined);

if (map.has('foo')) {
  console.log('Map has "foo" key');
}

if (map.has('bar')) {
  console.log('Map has "bar" key');
}
```

You would use `Map.has` for the same reason that you would use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` for checking whether an object has a certain property - using `obj[prop]` to check if the `prop` exists just isn't good enough in certain cases.

It's not an issue of performance - rather, it's because in some cases, there's just *no other way*. (`.has` is also more readable, though you said to ignore that part)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we're storing Objects into a Map :

```
const myMap = new Map(/* collection of objects */);`
```

In code samples, we can ofen see this :

```
function search(key) {
    if (myMap.has(key)) return null;
    let obj = myMap.get(key);
    return obj;
}
```

In case the key exists in the Map, we're searching for it 2 times : .has() then .get() !

The function can be optimized this way :

```
function search(key) {
    const obj = myMap.get(key);
    return obj || null;
}
```

But what if, instead of Objects we're storing primitive values ?

If the key exists, but its associated value is falsy (zero, false, empty string...), the last line will return null !

Of course, we could do this : `return obj !== undefined ? obj : null`

But we're lazy programmers, so let's use the nullish coalescing operator ??

```
function search(key) {
    const value = myMap.get(key);
    return value ?? null;
}
```

This will do the trick, wether we're dealing with Objects or primitive values :-)

Personnally, I never use the Map.prototype.has() method.
Do you know examples where it could be useful ?